# Why python does not see dist-packages when in virtualenv?

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, virtualenv

I needed to use opencv with python on my ubuntu 12.04 so I used this tutorial http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/ .

Unfortunately it came with somethin I do not quite understand - virtualenv. Now after completeing tutorial I have a problem. When I deactivate my virtualenv inside python I can see my dist-packages like numpy, matplotlib but dont see opencv (cv2), but when I use virtualenv inside python I can see opencv but no matplotlib or numpy.

To make a point: I need to make python see all of my dist-packages.

*I found a way that works but is so inelegant i cannot live with it - I can create function called in **init** that modifies sys path.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualenv is specifically designed to give you a clean python development environment. i.e. a fresh copy of python and any packages you need should then be installed while in the virtual env.

You can think of it like containers if you use Docker etc.

Main point is, if you want to use a package in virtual env, just use pip install ... while inside the env.

Comment: wow thats something :D It was information I needed, will try to read a little about it

Comment: I think I cannot edit comment twice therefore new one.
@pypypy could you explain why I need to use 'pip install' instead of 'sudo pip install' ? Because this is what I noticed.

Comment: Sudo elevates the action to super user level. This is not required for virtualenv because you control the local sandbox.